# How do we initialize Page factory in selenium webdriver c#

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

Do we have page objects for selenium webdriver c# ?

I am trying to work out Page objects with selenium webdriver with c# binding , unable to find any .

is there any statement that will mimic the initialization of page objects in c# , just like the below in java:
ClassName obj=PageFactory.initElements(driverName, ClassName.class);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options in C#, and they're remarkably similar to what you'd use with Java. The .NET `PageFactory` implementation is located in the `WebDriver.Support.dll` assembly, which means you'll need to add a reference to it in your project. Once you have that, you can use

```
// Assume MyPageObjectPage is your custom page object class.
// Of course, your constructor would likely be different, so
// you would need to change this to match your actual class
// structure.
// Further assume that driver is your IWebDriver instance.
MyPageObjectPage page = new MyPageObjectPage();
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, page);
```

Alternatively, if you'd like to use the .NET generics version of the same code, you could do something like this:

```
// Same assumptions as previous example.
MyPageObjectPage page = PageFactory.InitElements<MyPageObjectPage>(driver);
```

Note, however, that using the generic version places some restrictions on your page object class. Specifically, it must expose a constructor that takes a single parameter, and that parameter must be of type `IWebDriver`.